# What should a shop's products news feed contain?

Tags: feeds, syndication, shopping

I'm thinking about integrating some sort of (Atom) news feed into a shopping system, but I'm not sure how to go about it, except that I want the URIs to be the same for each representation (HTML, Atom). Let me explain through an example:

Let's say you have some **arbitrary product listing page** (red shoes for women). What would make the most sense to have as a news feed for that kind of URI?

Should the feed always contain all the matching products and only update the *date* on each feed entry if something (like price or availability) has changed? Would I have to update the entry's unique ID, too? Or should the feed only contain actual changes to the data, like "Product X now costs Y.YY"?

This also matters because the first way, I wouldn't have to store/persist feed entries, and that sounds good to me. But in the end it matters to me more what the best use for end users would be.

Comment: Can you edit this to contain fewer questions so that it's easier to read and answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`updated`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.15) (which is required) must contain the date/time of the last *significant* modification (e.g., price change, added/removed features, etc., but not for corrections of spelling mistakes, or some unimportant change of a description).

[`published`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.9) (which is optional) contains the date since when the product is added to the shop.

You must not change the [`id`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.6) when you update a product (an entry needs to have the same `id` "across all time and space", i.e., if you have a product which is contained in several different feeds, always use the same `id` for it.)

> Or should the feed only contain actual changes to the data, like "Product X now costs Y.YY"?

Unusual, but possible, of course (in this case, you’d need to use a new `id` for each entry!). I’d expect such a feed for a single product, not for category entries resp. search results. But if you think this is useful to your visitors, why not add both feeds?

```
<link rel="alternate" 
      type="application/atom+xml" 
      href="red-shoes-for-women_products.xml" 
      title="All products in the 'Red shoes (women)' category" />

<link rel="alternate" 
      type="application/atom+xml" 
      href="red-shoes-for-women_changes.xml" 
      title="All changes to products in the 'Red shoes (women)' category" />
```

(Note that the first feed in the `head` element should be the more important (resp. default) one.)