# Can a website have multiple RSS feeds? How would the <link> and <channel> elements look?

Tags: web-crawlers, rss, feeds

If I wanted to, for example, create three RSS feeds on my site to better allow users to subscribe specifically to the section in which they were interested, could I have three separate XML files at the server root?

If so, what are the mechanics of doing so? How do you use `<link>` meta tags on the home page?  Would each feed have a `<channel>` element with the same properties, or different ones? What does a crawler see when it goes to fetch the content?

Comment: I've seen plenty of sites that have multiple RSS feeds, so I don't think this is an issue. Re how to set these up, it would depend on exactly how your content is organized and what each RSS feed is supposed to do.

Comment: @barrycarter Thanks, are there any resources that would demonstrate how to do this? Essentially I have main blog posts, link posts, and a podcast. I would like these all to be separate feeds, i.e. blog.xml, link.xml, pods.xml.

Comment: Are you using WordPress? Some other CMS? RSS feeds aren't automatic... you need something to actually create them.

Comment: I am using a Virtual Host (on DigitalOcean) running a FreeBSD box, using lighttpd, and am uploading xml files to the document-root.

Comment: OK, but are you using a content management system? If you could give us a link, we might be able to help more, but not sure if the rules allow that or consider it "advertising".

Comment: No I am not, I am uploading them manually, though that shouldn't make a difference as far as my original question is concerned. Just to stay on the right side of the rules, I'll leave out the link.

Comment: OK, if you're uploading HTML files manually, you'll need to find software to create RSS feeds. Most blogging software includes this already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50252/discussion-between-brandon-bradley-and-barrycarter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s perfectly fine to offer multiple feeds. You could even offer [multiple feeds for the *same* items](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/100296/17633), e.g., one for the full content and one for excerpts.

There is nothing that would have to be changed in a feed just because there exist other feeds. So an RSS feed’s `channel` element would contain the same content as if the feed were the only one.

Linking multiple feeds in the `head` ([example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/56592/17633)) works exactly like linking one feed in the `head`. Best practices when linking multiple feeds:

- **The first feed link should be the default feed**, as this is the feed that will be used for autodiscovery. An example where this might be relevant: a feed reader that allows users to provide a webpage URL (instead of a feed URL) might add the default feed.

  [Liferea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liferea) does this, for example.
- **Each feed should get a `title`**, as this allows users to understand what the feeds contain. An example where this might be relevant: a client that lists the linked feeds might show their titles.

  [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox) does this, for example:

  [image: Firefox: in the feed list, each feed title is displayed]

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity.  Can you address the issue about `<channel>` elements in the feeds?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Not sure I understand what OP is getting at with these side questions. I added a paragraph and linked an example.